# Array objects not being printed in input fields and sql query not receiving the id value

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am getting the id from another page but i am not being able to pass it to the sql query. If i define any value to $id instead of 0 then the query works but otherwise it fails.
Secondly, i would like to display the values of the array in respective input fields. I tried using

```
<?php
echo $result_array['institutename'][0];
?>
```

in the body part but it didnt work out.

My rest code is as follows:
(I know the mysql functions are deprecated but i would move on to mysqli as soon as i have solved this problem)

```
 <?php
 include 'connect.php';
 $id=0;
 $result_array=array();

 if(isset($_REQUEST['id'])){ 
    $id=(int)$_REQUEST['id'];
    //$uid=$id;
    if(!empty($id)){
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM institute WHERE id =$id";
        $result = mysql_query($sql);
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
            $result_array[]=$row;
        }

    }
}



if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' && $_POST['form_institutedetails'] == 'saveinstitutedetails') 
{
$mysql_table='institute';

$institutename = $_POST['institutename'];
$established = $_POST['established'];
$regno = $_POST['reg_no'];
$branch = $_POST['branch'];
$initials = $_POST['initials'];
$address=$_POST['address'];
$pin=$_POST['pin'];
$contact1=$_POST['contact1'];
$contact2=$_POST['contact2'];
$contact3=$_POST['contact3'];
$fax1=$_POST['fax1'];
$fax2=$_POST['fax2'];
$email=$_POST['email'];
$website=$_POST['website'];

if(isset($_POST['head_office'])){
    $head_office=$_POST['head_office'];
}
else{
    $head_office="Branch";
}   



if (!preg_match("/^.+@.+\..+$/", $email))
{
    $error_message = 'Email is not a valid email address. Please check and try again.';
 }


if (empty($error_message))
{
     $newinstitutename = mysql_real_escape_string($institutename);
     $newestablished = mysql_real_escape_string($established);
     $newregno = mysql_real_escape_string($regno);
     $newbranch = mysql_real_escape_string($branch);
     $newaddress = mysql_real_escape_string($address);
     $newpin = mysql_real_escape_string($pin);
     $newemail = mysql_real_escape_string($email);
     $newwebsite = mysql_real_escape_string($website);
     $ho = mysql_real_escape_string($head_office);

    include 'connect.php';

    $sql = "UPDATE `".$mysql_table."` SET `institutename`='$newinstitutename', `established`='$newestablished', `regno`='$newregno', `branch`='$newbranch', `initials`='$initials', `address`='$newaddress', `pin`='$newpin', `contact1`='$contact1', `contact2`='$contact2', `contact3`='$contact3', `fax1`='$fax1', `fax2`='$fax2', `email`='$newemail', `website`='$newwebsite', `head_office`='$ho' WHERE `id`=$id";

$result = mysql_query($sql, $db);
    mysql_close($db);

    $error_message='Updated Successfully!.';
}
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are unsure about the structure of an array, you can always do a `print_r` during development.

```
print_r($result_array);
```

In this case, it is an index array of associative arrays.

To access the first record's `institutename` (and probably the only record since it looks like you used an unique key in your query), you can use

```
echo $result_array[0]['institutename'];
```

Comment: Okay, now I am being able to read the data from the array but when I use it in an html form and submit it, it gives undefined offset:0 notice.

Comment: okay now i solved the offset error by using 

     header('Location: '.$success_page);

but still now I an unable to solve the id problem stated in the question.